# Writing a trigger to mention reporter of a case

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I have a tough time with Salesforce. How do I go about writing a trigger to specify the person who created the case as the reporter in the "reported by" field?

This is code I have written:

```java
trigger caseRepoter on Case (before insert) {

   List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();

   for (Case cas: Trigger.New) {
      if (cas.CreatorName != null) {
         Case c = new Case();
         c.CreatorName = cas.Id;
         cases.add(c);
      }
   }

   insert cases;
}
```

`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SObjects have a CreatedBy standard field that is a Lookup to the User that created the object. So in your foreach loop, it would be cas.CreatedById